# What is a sympelctic bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

What is a symplectic bundle? Is it a fibre bundle or a vector bundle? I am hoping for a not-very-technical answer because I'm not familiar with bundles in general. Sorry for that.

PS: This symplectic bundle enters in the definition of a special Kahler manifold (or in maths what they call projective Kahler manifold I suppose).

Any answer is very welcomed.

Comment: Where are you seeing the term? A reference for context would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not terminology I've heard before, but one might predict (and it turns out to be true) that the authors here mean "symplectic vector bundle". This is a smooth vector bundle $E \to M$ such that each fiber has the (smoothly varying) structure of a [symplectic vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space).

One could certainly make a notion of a fiber bundle whose fibers were symplectic manifolds but I claim this would probably not be that interesting a notion unless the base or total space had further structure (eg, Langrangian fibrations are interesting).

Comment: Initially I thought that $TM$ being a symplectic vector bundle is the same thing as $M$ being symplectic, but it isn't as there is no closedness condition.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I think the term people use for that is "almost symplectic", not that I've seen people say much about such structures.

Comment: Thank you, I would be grateful if you tell me what you meant by $E$ and $M$ here? Also, if there's an intuitive way to think about fibers, I would be glad to hear it from you.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for your input too!

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese would you know what Mike meant by $E$ and $M$?

Comment: Symplectic fibre bundles are interesting -- they are discussed for instance in McDuff-Salamon's book _Introduction to Symplectic Topology_. They are how Thurston constructed examples of symplectic manifolds that are not K\"ahler. Lefschetz fibrations are examples of these as well, but with additional singularities.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: $E$ is the total space of the vector bundle and $M$ is the base. You can think of the vector bundle as associating a vector space smoothly to each point $x \in M$. Then, $E$ is the union of all these vector spaces. You have a projection map from $E$ to $M$ that forgets the vector and just remembers the point you are at. This is explained in more detail in the Wikipedia article. They use $E$ for the total space but $X$ for the base, unlike here, where Mike Miller wrote $M$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle